# Не возвращает ожидаемый результат. Где ошибка?

Tags: php

Делаю пример по книге. Должно вернуть: "Автор: Джордж Мартин"
А возвращает: "Автор: "
Я где-то допустил ошибку?

```
<?php

    class ShopProduct {

        public $title = "Стандартный товар"; // свойство класса
        public $producerMainName = "Фамилия автора";
        public $producerFirstName = "Имя автора";
        public $price = 0;

        /*add constructor*/
        function __construct ($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price) {

            $this -> title = $title;    //this исп. для присвоения значений соответствующим свойствам объекта
            $this -> producerFirstName = $firstName;
            $this -> producerMainName = $mainName;
            $this -> price = $price;
        }

        /*add method*/
        function getProducer () {

            return "{$this -> ProducerFirstName}"
                    ."{$this -> ProducerMainName}";
        }
}

$product1 = new ShopProduct ("Битва королей", "Джордж", "Мартин", 10);
echo "Автор: {$product1 -> getProducer () }\n";
// => 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Боже, вы зачем значения через строку возвращаете из метода getProducer? Замените на это.

```
return $this->producerFirstName." ".$this->producerMainName;
```

Ваша ошибка в том, что надо писать producerFirstName, как указано в описании свойств класса, а вы пишите ProducerFirstName.

Пожалуйста, почитайте про стандарты PSR, оформление кода, геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: спасибо, буду внимательнее

Answer (score 0):

А вы принципиально игнорируете предупреждения PHP? В них же всё подробно рассказывается:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: ShopProduct::$ProducerFirstName in ...
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: ShopProduct::$ProducerMainName in ...
```

Просите `ProducerFirstName`, а есть `producerFirstName`, и т.д.

Comment: меня sublime так заботливо не предупреждает!